# Ignoring fake usernames

Tags: c#, algorithm

So I am using an api that returns usernames to me. In them are some fake ones like:

```
8spZKYf1t2
xOzJzaYJe2
0x5jD4xmTM
PJFBoDFJsW
UZV908nNF7
CRuMGgh1bM
lyhDRamtFf
wELYyunHZU
NC8ZbYCjig
plK2KtwQwE
EKRlRLRitP
0CULcA8lIR
Yyi2NV3P8n
```

Anybody know a good algorithm to ignore these?

Comment: How do you know its a fake username. I mean **0CULcA8lIR** sounds like a pretty cool username to me. :)

Comment: @Haris, yeah it would be a cool alien username though :)

Comment: The point of my comment is, Do you have a clear cut way of defining what a valid username could be? Some username might look fake but can be genuine.

Comment: @Haris: In my opinion this is what the question is about. Clearly, the clear distinction of valid username from the rest is the key part, not the implementation. Why else would you ask for a *good* algorithm, if it is not about some clever heuristics?

Comment: Very valid question. Also look at Matt Timmermans answer. It goes in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a database of usernames in order to learn the difference between real ones and fake one.  Call this the "training set":

1. From the training set, calculate the number of occurrences for each 3 letter combination.  From "mtimmerm", for example, you would add counts for "mti", "tim", "imm", etc.  Let `N(x)` be the number of counts for `x` in the training set, and let `TOTAL` be the total number of counts.  Let `F(x) = (N(x)+1)/(TOTAL+1)`  This will be our estimate for the frequency at which that 3 letter combination occurs in usernames.
2. Given a candidate username `U`, for each 3-letter combination `x` in `U`, calculate H(x) = -log(F(X)).  Add all these together and divide by `length(U)-2` (the number of combinations) to get `H(U)`.  The is a measure of how 'unrealistic' `U` is.

Calculate `H(U)` for a bunch of usernames, and you should find that it is much higher for fake ones.

If you want to learn the theory behind how this works, the google word is "Entropy": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

What we are doing is making a statistical model for usernames, and then calculating how 'unusual' each username is according to that model.  This is actually a measure of how many bits it would take to store the username if we used our model to compress it (sort of -- I simplified the calculations but they should be accurate enough relative to one another).  Randomly generated usernames (which we are assuming are fake) will take more information to store than real ones.

NOTE:  it's nice if the training set doesn't contain any fake usernames, but it won't make too much difference as long as most of them are real.  Also note that it's not quite right to test names *from* the training set.  If you're going to test names from the training set, then subtract `1/(TOTAL+1)` from each `F(X)` so the username's own counts aren't included when testing it.